# Is it better to delete our own contentious questions, or allow them to be closed by vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, deleted-questions, new-users

I recently asked a question here on Meta which collected at least two or three upvotes, but accumulated downvotes almost as quickly. When it got to its fourth vote to close, I took the hint and deleted it myself (understanding self-deletion as an acceptable and preferred method for self-policing). Its (net) score was zero at the time.

Looking back on my decision, though, I got to wondering: **Is it correct to view close-votes as a tiebreaker when a question's vote score is contentious**, or is it more appropriate to let other users close it when/after that seems to be the inevitable result?

Comment: `closure != deletion`. Questions can be put on hold in the hope that they will be improved; note that most of the close reasons refer to how the post could be improved and reopened. And there's nothing necessarily wrong with contentious content on Meta, as long as it's *constructive*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In this case, I think the problem was that the data needed to answer the question came from relatively (if not entirely) inaccessible sources. I asked it on the basis that I didn't know if there was an answer or not; if there was, it would be really interesting and probably very useful, if not, then the question is well-meaning but forgettable. The close votes were all that it was opinion-based, but more clearly, I think that it's more that there were just too many factors involved and assigning weight to them would devolve into speculation. I can't think of how to fix that. :I

Comment: @jonrsharpe That said, your point about closure not being deletion is well taken.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should delete a post when it has no content of value to the community.  Whether it's contentious, or even if it's open or closed has nothing to do with it.  If you think there is something of value, or something that could become something of value, leave it.  If you think that there's nothing there of value, and it won't be turned into something of value, delete it.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm having a lot of difficulty assessing the value of `discussion` Meta questions to the community, since many of the ones I've seen (and even asked) are, by their nature, difficult to answer with certainty. In these cases, I assumed that the *content* of the discussion was the value of the thing and that the conversation, which ought to speak to the question, contained the value-proper. Because I'm not sure if that's the case, though, I can't really say if it was legitimately valuable or not. Do you know if there's any sort of guideline relating to this kind of situation?

Comment: @Augusta If someone else asked that question and you saw it would you consider it a waste of your time to read it, or not?  If other people end up reading the post do you think that they will overwhelmingly regret having read the post, or be glad that they were able to read it?  If you think that it's likely there will be decent number of future readers of the question who will have been better off having read that question than never seen it, then keep it.  If not, delete it.

Comment: @Servy - I think what you are both running into is the difficulty of judging value, especially when it comes to META type questions.  A lot of times it is easy to see whether something will be of value to others or not, but sometimes...

Comment: Sounds like we need a new site, http://meta.meta.stackoverflow.com - down the rabbit hole...

Comment: @StevenPenny I'm glad that I am not the only one who thought that this absurd-sounding thing would be useful.

Comment: @StevenPenny ['Time to re-read "Gödel, Escher, Bach".'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375/165773)

Answer (score 16):

Meta questions are a little different than questions on the main site. A question that is down voted into a hole may still have some redeeming value, if nothing else it serves as a "someone already asked this question and it wasn't well received" and if someone else asks the question anyway it can be closed as a duplicate of your question.

That's not saying that "no Meta question should ever be deleted", just saying that Meta questions sometimes have value even when they're unpopular.

[As Servy said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294287/1947286) it usually boils down to whether it will have any value to future readers.